# Run python script with matlab.engine without having to install MATLAB

Tags: python-3.x, matlab

I am writing a Python script that makes use of a few of MATLAB functions by importing the matlab.engine module. I would like to know please, if there is a way for me to bundle up the script as well as the Matlab functions and share them with whoever I want without them being forced to install Matlab and follow the instructions to couple Matlab and python?

PS:I cannot re-write the MATLAB scripts in python.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot run MATLAB without MATLAB. There’s the MATLAB Compiler, which lets you create a stand-alone executable or dynamic link library out of MATLAB code, but I don’t know if this works for integration with Python.

Comment: Thank you Cris for your answer. So you are saying, I should at least include the Matlab compiler with my files, right ? (I'll check if it works). But then I guess, I should adda README file to describe to the user the steps to follow to properly couple Python to Matlab.

Comment: The MATLAB Compiler is a separate toolbox, which you need to get a license to if you don't have it. You can then "compile" your M-file functions into a form that can be run with the MCR, which is a free download. This means, you pay for the Compiler so that the people that you distribute your code to don't need to pay for MATLAB to run your code. But they still need to install the MCR. The MCR is a free version of MATLAB that can only run stuff prepared by the MATLAB Compiler. It's a big download.

Comment: [The MATLAB Compiler does work with Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html).

Comment: Oh, I get it now.. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hello @Cris, I am having few problems using the matlab compiler. Have you ever used it before and came across this error: Error using figure
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run  web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6', '-browser'). ?